# How to read a big Azure blob storage file block by block

Tags: python, azure, stream, azure-blob-storage

I want to read a huge Azure blob storage file and stream its content to Event-Hub. I found this example,

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

bb = BlockBlobService(account_name='', account_key='')
container_name = ""
blob_name_to_download = "test.txt"
file_path ="/home/Adam/Downloaded_test.txt"

bb.get_blob_to_path(container_name, blob_name_to_download, file_path, open_mode='wb', 
 snapshot=None, start_range=None, end_range=None, validate_content=False, 
 progress_callback=None, max_connections=2, lease_id=None, 
 if_modified_since=None, if_unmodified_since=None, 
 if_match=None, if_none_match=None, timeout=None)
```

But in this way, you can't get blocks in a loop, which I want to do. So, how can I modify this code for my case?

Comment: Can I give you pseudo code?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes, sure.

Comment: Please see my answer below. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice, there are two parameters in `get_blob_to_path` method - `start_range` and `end_range`. These two parameters would allow you to read blob's data in chunk.

What you need to do is get the blob's properties first to find its length and then repeatedly call `get_blob_xxx` method to get data in chunks. I used `get_blob_to_text` method but you can see other methods [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.baseblobservice?view=azure-python-previous.).

Here's the pseudo code I came up with. HTH.

```
bb = BlockBlobService(account_name='', account_key='')
container_name = ""
blob_name_to_download = "test.txt"
file_path ="/home/Adam/Downloaded_test.txt"

#First get blob properties. We would want to find out blob's content length
blob = bb.get_blob_properties()

#extract content length from blob's properties
blob_size = blob.properties.content_length

#now let's say we want to fetch 1MB chunk at a time so we loop and fetch 1MB content at a time.
start = 0
end = blob_size
chunk_size = 1 * 1024 * 1024 #1MB
do
    start_range = start
    end_range = start + chunk_size - 1
    blob_chunk_content = bb.get_blob_to_text(container_name, blob_name, 
        encoding='utf-8', snapshot=None, start_range=start_range, end_range=end_range, 
        validate_content=False, progress_callback=None, max_connections=2, 
        lease_id=None, if_modified_since=None, if_unmodified_since=None, 
        if_match=None, if_none_match=None, timeout=None)
    #blob_chunk_content will have 1 MB data. Do whatever you like with it.
    start = end_range + 1
while (start < end)
```

Comment: And if I want to divide the data at lines level (I have json data on each line, so I do not want the chunk to end up in the middle of a line), would I have to write my own logic for that? Or does the API provide something for that as well?

Comment: You will need to write your own logic. Blob storage does not really know what's the content you're storing. In that case you will need to fetch the entire blob and then parse its contents to create JSON objects.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Gaurav. It works! I have put the Python version as an answer, so that other people with the same problem can refer to that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Python version of Gaurav's Pseudocode. Note that I had to install the `azure.storage.blob` package by using `pip install azure-storage-blob==2.1.0`.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

bb = BlockBlobService(account_name='<storage_account_name>', account_key='<sas_key>')
container_name = "<container_name>"
blob_name = "<dir>/<file>"

#First get blob properties. We would want to find out blob's content length
blob = bb.get_blob_properties(container_name=container_name, blob_name=blob_name)

#extract content length from blob's properties
blob_size = blob.properties.content_length

#now let's say we want to fetch 1MB chunk at a time,
# so we loop and fetch 1MB content at a time.
start = 0
end = blob_size
chunk_size = 1 * 1024 * 1024 # 1MB

while start < end:
  start_range = start
  end_range = start + chunk_size - 1
  blob_chunk_content = bb.get_blob_to_text(container_name, blob_name, 
    encoding='utf-8', snapshot=None, start_range=start_range, end_range=end_range, 
    validate_content=False, progress_callback=None, max_connections=2, 
    lease_id=None, if_modified_since=None, if_unmodified_since=None, 
    if_match=None, if_none_match=None, timeout=None)
  print(blob_chunk_content.content)
  start = end_range + 1
```